# FPDF Cell function new line

Tags: php, fpdf

I have this code `$fpdf->Cell(0,0,$name,0,1);` but the problem is that it doesn't print newline which is supposed to be printed because of the last value 1 which pertains to the `Ln` of FPDF which means the next cell should be printed below the previous cell. Here is my full code:

```
foreach($data->result() as $row){
    $mName = $row->middle_name; $name = $row->first_name . ' ' . $mName[0] . '. ' . $row->last_name;
    $fpdf->Cell(0,0,$name,0,1);
    $fpdf->Cell(0,0,'Address:',0,1);
}
```